# iOS Swift: Expandable/Collapsable View that contains a Horizontally Scrolling List

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, expand

Im am relatively new to Swift/iOS and i have a quite complex task to Accomplish, and i want to know the best way for doing that.

I need to have a Custom View. This View displays some content, e.g. a news-article. If the user taps on the View, it expands and shows a more detailed version of the news article. Also, the user cann scroll horizontally (in the expanded or collapsed state) to get to the next article.

[A Visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf1Bo.png)

I searched for each problem individually. For scrolling, i found that i can use a scrollview with paging enabled, so that each swipe will lead to the next article. But im not sure if that is the best solution for my problem.
For expanding/Collapsing a view, i only have the idea to programmatically set the size of the view to fill the screen, so that auto layout would no longer display everything that is located beneath our custom view. Would that be possible? And is there any better solution?

Comment: Your question is too broad - try to be more detailed... *"horizontally scrolls subviews ... needs to expand"*? Do you mean you want to expand to show more scrolling subviews? Or you want to expand to show something else? What happens from there? Does the user interact with the "expanded" view? You need to edit your question and ***really*** make clear what you are asking - preferably, show some images of what you have done so far, and how you want it to end up looking / functioning.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I Hope it is more clear now

Comment: OK - `UIPageViewController` is a good candidate. It has the paging functionality and management built right in. You *could* use a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled, but suppose you have 100 news articles? That gives you a *lot* of content to manage with a scroll view. As to expand/collapse, you'll probably want to try a couple different approaches. You could **hide** the "other content" and let constraints "auto-zoom" your articles view... you could `.present` it in a modal view... It depends a bit on the overall design of your app, and what else may need to happen.